# Is SvelteKit 1.0 +server.ts code EVER exposed to clients?

Tags: svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I am deploying my Svelte app via Vercel and am using Svelte's server endpoints to host serverless functions. I want to make sure that the code used in serverless functions is NEVER exposed to the client as it contains sensitive API keys. May layout is currently:

```
/src/routes/api/users/+server.ts
/src/routes/api/api_keys.ts
```

`api_keys.ts` is imported by the `+server.ts` file. Is it correct to assume that the secrets stored in `api_keys.ts` will not be exposed to clients?
I think the technically more "secure" solution would be to expose the keys via environment variables only at deploy time and for local development. I don't know how to do achieve that with Vercel however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although unusual, it is possible to import files like

```
/src/routes/api/users/+server.ts
/src/routes/api/api_keys.ts
```

into publicly-facing client files. (Sometimes VS Code just auto-imports files you don't want imported, etc)

So SvelteKit provides [server-only modules](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/server-only-modules) expressly for this purpose:

> Like a good friend, SvelteKit keeps your secrets. When writing your
> backend and frontend in the same repository, it can be easy to
> accidentally import sensitive data into your front-end code
> (environment variables containing API keys, for example). SvelteKit
> provides a way to prevent this entirely: server-only modules.

---

I would put `api_keys.ts` in `$lib/server/api_keys.ts` (`src/lib/server/api_keys.ts`)

SvelteKit private environment variables can be safely used knowing that using them in any client-side code will result in a build error:

- [`$env/static/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private)
- [`$env/dynamic/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private)

Any environment variables that could possibly be leaked to the client must be prefixed with `PUBLIC_` and imported from slightly different modules.